# Section title in line with text, how to?

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

What I want to obtain documents formatted as showed in the attached screen-shot part. this is what I want: the title of a section in line with the text and all the text indented so that it looks as if the title occupies a column while the text occupies another column.
I tried using columns but that's not the way to go. At least I didn't figure out some workable way to use column the way I want. Then I tried using a  package "titlesec" and could make it partially work but got completely stuck.

I hope somebody can help me out?

[image]

Comment: If you've already made some progress, please paste your results so far as a [minimal example document](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). It's much easier for others to help if they only need to add some lines of code to an existing document than rewriting everything from scratch.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! This can be done with the `titlesec` package, redefining the section format as `leftmargin` (see § 3.1 of the documentation).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example, loosely based on an example in the `titlesec` documentation:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[left=7cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]
  {\titleline[r]{\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}\vspace{3mm}\Large\sffamily\bfseries\filright}
 {}{0pt}{}

\titlespacing{\section} {4cm}{0pt}{1em}
\begin{document}
\section{Asynchronous oversampling}
\label{sec:asynchr-overs}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```